# python numpy not true detection logo in some image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

i want to find logo and replace with new logos, with opencv and python find position then replace new logo. circle logo worked fine, but minibox and largebox logos in some images not work well.
In my code, it does not recognize a series of photos correctly and does not respect the size

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2

shapeList=['circle','mini','large']
adad=6
shape=shapeList[2]

def logoPosition(adad,shape):
    picture= np.array(Image.open(f"usa{adad}.jpg").convert('RGBA'))
    box=np.array(Image.open(f'{shape}box.jpg').convert('RGBA'))
    heat_map=cv2.matchTemplate(picture,box,cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
    h,w= box.shape[:2]
    y,x =np.unravel_index(np.argmax(heat_map),heat_map.shape)
    return h,w,y,x


def replaceNewLogoBox(adad,shape,h,w,y,x):
    image=Image.open(f'usa{adad}.jpg')
    shape_logo=Image.open(f'replace{shape}box.jpg')
    image_copy=image.copy()
    shape_logo_copy=shape_logo.resize((w,h))
    image_copy.paste(shape_logo_copy,(x,y))
    image_copy.save(f'usa_{adad}.jpg')



h,w,y,x,=logoPosition(adad,shape)
replaceNewLogoBox(adad,shape,h,w,y,x)
```

in usa7.jpg work truly , but in other image ( usa6.jpg ) not work perfect

[usa7.jpg](https://aghightube.ir/usa7.jpg) ====> [usa_7.jpg](https://aghightube.ir/usa_7.jpg)
[usa6.jpg](https://aghightube.ir/usa6.jpg) ====> [usa_6.jpg](https://aghightube.ir/usa_6.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by "not work perfect" ?

Comment: see the example images

Comment: anyone dont can help me ?!